# VBA: Pull data from website using objElement and objCollection

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to pull data from a website using objElement and objCollection. Relevant and working code is as follows:

```
    Sub Step6()
Dim LoanNumX As Long
Dim LastX As String
Dim Phone1X As String
Dim Phone2X As String
Dim PiX As String
Dim TiX As String
Dim myText2 As String

    ActiveWorkbook.Save


    Range("M2").Select


Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
LastX = ActiveCell.Value
ActiveCell.Offset(, -12).Select
BigX = ActiveCell.Value
Phone1X = "N/A"
Phone2X = "N/A"
PiX = "N/A"
TiX = "N/A"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "https://website.com"

Application.StatusBar = "https://website.com is loading. Please wait..."

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("input")

             A1 = 0
While A1 < objCollection.Length
            If objCollection(A1).Name = "networkId" Then
                    objCollection(A1).Value = "ID"

            Else
            If objCollection(A1).Name = "password" Then
                    objCollection(A1).Value = "PW"

            Else
            If objCollection(A1).Name = "btnLogin" Then
                    Set objElement = objCollection(A1)
                    objElement.Click
            End If
            End If
            End If
            A1 = A1 + 1
Wend

    Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
```

The above code is fully functional. The code below comes directly after the code above, and issues arise:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Search form submission. Please wait..."


Set objCollection = IE.Document.getElementsbyTagName("input")

    L = 0
While L < objCollection.Length
            If objCollection(L).Name = "account" Then
                    objCollection(L).Value = BigX
          Else
           If objCollection(L).Name = "lastName" Then
                   objCollection(L).Value = LastX

           Else
            If objCollection(L).Type = "image" Then
                   Set objElement = objCollection(L)
                    objElement.Click
            End If
            End If
            End If
            L = L + 1
    Wend
```

For some reason, the above code is skipped. I do not undersand why, but the macro never goes through the while statement - it's as though L > objCollection.Length from the beginning. If I step into the script, it jumps from:

```
        While L < objCollection.Length
```

To the code segment following:

```
Wend
```

The result is that IE is opened, the initial page is accessed, login data entered and submitted, resulting page displayed, and then another instance of IE is opened and the loop repeats. IE, initial page, login data, resulting page, IE, initial page, login data, resulting page, IE...so when I force the macro to quit I end up with a number of instances all stuck on the same page.

I've tried a few different approaches but have been unable to solve the problem thus far.

Here's the data I'm after in HTML:

```
    <td><input type="text" name="account" maxlength="9" size="25" value="" onkeypress="accountSelected()" class="inputbox"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" size="25" value="" onkeypress="lastNameSelected()" class="inputbox"></td>
    <input type="image" src="images/search.gif" alt="Search">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Also, I am using MS Excel 2007 and IE 7. I know that IE 7 doesn't support IE.Document.getElementsbyClassName, so that rules that out as a potential solution. I know that both Excel 2007 and IE 7 are outdated, but I cannot update them.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved on from this question, as I have now pinpointed the real issue.

This is my updated issue:
[VBA: Enter data into a form within one of many frames on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519868/vba-pull-data-from-a-form-within-one-of-many-frames-on-a-website)